# How to remove an object from read-only

Tags: c++11, copy-constructor

I'm doing an assignment and I have a little problem with a function I'm supposed to write, here are the instructions for the function.

1. Create an unsigned char variable named 'value' and assign this to 1.
2. Use the left-shift bit operator to determine set the bit that offset_ identifies.
3. Use bitwise-AND with datum_ and the result from the previous bullet.
4. Return true if the previous bullet's answer is != 0.

The first Error is:

```
error: assignment of member ‘bool_array<13ul>::bit_proxy::datum_’ in read-only object
    datum_ &= (value << offset_);
```

Code:

```
#include <limits>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>
class bool_array{
public:
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using value_type = bool;

    //default constructor
    bool_array(){
        std::memset(bits_, 0, sizeof(unsigned char)*MAX);
    }

    //copy constructor
    bool_array(bool_array const& a){
        std::memcpy(this->bits_, &a.bits_, sizeof(unsigned char)*MAX);
    }

    //copy assignment
    bool_array& operator = (bool_array const& a){
        std::memcpy(this->bits_, &a.bits_, sizeof(unsigned char)*MAX);
        return *this;
    }

    //destructor
    ~bool_array() = default;

    //getting access to size()
    constexpr size_type size() const{
        return N;
    }

    class bit_proxy{
    private:
        unsigned char datum_;
        size_type const offset_;
    public:
        bit_proxy() = delete;

        //default copy constructor & assigment
        bit_proxy(bit_proxy const&) = default;
        bit_proxy& operator = (bit_proxy const&) = default;

        //default move constructor & assignment
        bit_proxy(bit_proxy&&) = default;
        bit_proxy& operator = (bit_proxy&&) = default;

        //default delete
        ~bit_proxy() = default;

        bit_proxy(unsigned char& datum, size_type offset) : datum_(datum), offset_(offset){
        }

        bit_proxy& operator = (bool b)
        {
            unsigned char value = 1;
            if(b)
                datum_ |= (value << offset_);
            else
                datum_ &=~ (value << offset_);
            return *this;
        }

        /*******************This is the function with the error**************************/
        operator bool() const
        {
            unsigned char value = 1;
            datum_ &= (value << offset_);
            //datum_ &= offset_;
            if(datum_ != 0)
                return true;
        }
        /*********************************Function ends here************************************************/
    };
    bit_proxy operator [](size_type i)
  {
    return bit_proxy{ bits_[i / std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits], 
        i % std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits }
    ;
  }

private:
    static constexpr auto MAX = N / std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits + (N % std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits != 0);
    unsigned char bits_[MAX];
};

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    bool_array<13> test;

    for(unsigned i=0; i !=13; ++i)
        cout << i << " : " << test[i] << '\n';

    for(unsigned i=0; i != 13; ++i){
        cout << i << " : " << test[i] << "; ";
        test[i] = true; 
        cout << test[i] << '\n';
    }

    for(unsigned i=0; i!= 13; ++i)
        cout << i << " : " << test[i] << '\n';

    for(unsigned i=0; i!= 13; ++i){
        cout << i << " : " << test[i] << "; ";
        test[i] = false;
        cout << test[i] << '\n';
    }

    for(unsigned i=0; i != 13; ++i)
        cout << i << " : "<< test[i] << '\n';

    cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Is that twiddle meant to be there? `datum_ &=~ (value << offset_);`

Comment: The assignment says "use bitwise and". Try using bitwise and instead of `&=`. The latter is not *quite* the bitwise and operator. Hint: bitwise and has no side effects, you will need to use its *result* somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `operator bool()` is defined as constant (doesn't modify the contents of the object), but you change a member variable. Either remove the `const` or don't modify `datum_`.